# ActiveRecord eager load multiple belongs_to associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, eager-loading

### The problem

I have the following ActiveRecord model:

```
class Person
  belongs_to :favourite_car, class_name: 'Car'
  belongs_to :business_car, class_name: 'Car'
  belongs_to :home_car, class_name: 'Car'
end
```

When I want to access all three of these associations, it generates three select queries:

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE cars.id = ?
```

This is essentially the *N+1 problem*.

Ideally, I'd like it to generate just one query of the form

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE cars.id IN (?, ?, ?)
```

### Possible solution

I could move this to a `has_many :through => :join_table` association with a column in the join table to indicate what the association type is, then use `includes([:join_table, :cars])` to eager load the associations. However, in this case it only reduces 3 queries to 2, and introduces an extra table.

### Another possible solution

Another possible solution would be to manually load the associations like so:

```
module EagerLoader
  def eager_load(*associations)
    reflections = associations.map { |association| self.class.reflections[association.to_sym] }
    raise 'Not all are valid associations' if reflections.any?(&:nil?)

    reflections.group_by { |association| association.klass }.each do |klass, reflections|
      load_associations(klass, reflections)
    end

    self

  end

private

  def load_associations(klass, reflections)

    primary_key = klass.primary_key

    ids = reflections.map { |reflection| public_send(reflection.foreign_key) }

    records = klass.where(id: ids)


    reflections.each_with_index do |reflection, i|
      record = records.find do |record|
        record.public_send(primary_key) == ids[i]
      end

      public_send("#{reflection.name}=", record)
    end

  end


end
```

I have tested it, and it works.

```
class Person
  include EagerLoader
end

Person.find(2).eager_load(:favorite_car, :business_car, :home_car)
```

However, this still does not help you when you want to do things like

```
Person.includes(:favourite_car, :business_car, :home_car)
```

For example, on the person index page. This reduces the number of queries from 3N+1 to 4, but only 2 are actually needed.

**Are there any better solutions to this problem?**

Comment: How does a favorite car differ rom a business car (in the model sense, that is)? When you go to access car data for a Person, do you typically need all three bits (the fave, biz and home cars)?

Comment: favourite_car, business_car and home_car are all just instances of Car, so there is no difference in the models. Almost all of the time, I need to access all three bits or none at all.

Comment: Sorry ... did not ask that well. What differentiates a fave car from a home car (is there a 'boolean' or 'type' column that differentiates these models)? In other words, how do you know that a Car is the favorite or business or home? (I really am asking for a reason ... not to be annoying :)).

Comment: Is there a reason a person does not have_one instead of belongs_to? Seems like this would be an easier set up. What does your table structure look like?

Comment: @craig.kaminsky There is a favourite_car_id, business_car_id, and home_car_id foreign key in the people table, as per activerecord conventions for belongs_to associations.

Comment: Ok, thanks ... just now back to SO and read @franksort's reply, which works well for meeting the single query req.

Comment: I have updated the question with a half-solution, but it still does more queries than necessary when doing `includes()` eager-loading

Comment: @CameronMartin Where did you pull that `EagerLoader` module from?  Is it already a part of the Rails core?

Comment: No, it's something I just made to eager load the associations. It only half solves my problem though, see the bottom of my edit.

Comment: @engineersmnky Do you mean a `has_one :through => ` with a join table for each of favourite_car, business_car, home_car? I can't have a has_one on Person with a belongs_to on Car, because Car needs to has_many people_as_favourite, people_as_business etc

Comment: "Possible Solution" as you list above is my choice of solutions. You are adding a table, but you are also removing 2 columns and making the data structure less restrictive. The possibility for expansion in the future is good (what if I want to add 'my 2nd favourite car'). Then the joining table will work well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a great post about manual Eager load.

http://mrbrdo.wordpress.com/2013/09/25/manually-preloading-associations-in-rails-using-custom-scopessql/

I guess this is what you have been looking for:

```
owners = People.all
association_name = :photos

owners.each do |owner|
   record = whatever_you_want

   association = owner.association(association_name)
   association.target = record
   association.set_inverse_instance(record)
end
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
> person_id = 1
> person = Person.includes(:favorite_car, :business_car, :home_car).where("people.id" = ?", person_id).references(:favorites_car, :business_car, :home_car)
> person[0].favorite_car
```

**app/models/person.rb**

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  # columns: id, name, favorite_car_id, business_car_id, home_car_id
  belongs_to :favorite_car, class_name: 'Car'
  belongs_to :business_car, class_name: 'Car'
  belongs_to :home_car, class_name: 'Car'
end
```

**app/models/car.rb**

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  # columns: id, name
  has_many :people
end
```

**Proof that this works:**

```
> Person.all
  Person Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "people".* FROM "people"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Person id: 1, favorite_car_id: 1, business_car_id: 2, home_car_id: 3, name: "Frankie", created_at: "2014-02-18 21:51:58", updated_at: "2014-02-18 21:53:34">]>

> Car.all
  Car Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "cars".* FROM "cars"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Car id: 1, name: "Mazda", created_at: "2014-02-18 21:52:16", updated_at: "2014-02-18 21:52:16">, #<Car id: 2, name: "Honda", created_at: "2014-02-18 21:52:20", updated_at: "2014-02-18 21:52:20">, #<Car id: 3, name: "BMW", created_at: "2014-02-18 21:52:24", updated_at: "2014-02-18 21:52:24">]>

> Person.includes(:favorite_car, :business_car, :home_car).where("people.id = ?", 1).references(:favorite_car, :business_car, :home_car)
  SQL (0.4ms)  SELECT "people"."id" AS t0_r0, "people"."favorite_car_id" AS t0_r1, "people"."business_car_id" AS t0_r2, "people"."home_car_id" AS t0_r3, "people"."name" AS t0_r4, "people"."created_at" AS t0_r5, "people"."updated_at" AS t0_r6, "cars"."id" AS t1_r0, "cars"."name" AS t1_r1, "cars"."created_at" AS t1_r2, "cars"."updated_at" AS t1_r3, "business_cars_people"."id" AS t2_r0, "business_cars_people"."name" AS t2_r1, "business_cars_people"."created_at" AS t2_r2, "business_cars_people"."updated_at" AS t2_r3, "home_cars_people"."id" AS t3_r0, "home_cars_people"."name" AS t3_r1, "home_cars_people"."created_at" AS t3_r2, "home_cars_people"."updated_at" AS t3_r3 FROM "people" LEFT OUTER JOIN "cars" ON "cars"."id" = "people"."favorite_car_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "cars" "business_cars_people" ON "business_cars_people"."id" = "people"."business_car_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "cars" "home_cars_people" ON "home_cars_people"."id" = "people"."home_car_id" WHERE (people.id = 1)
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Person id: 1, favorite_car_id: 1, business_car_id: 2, home_car_id: 3, name: "Frankie", created_at: "2014-02-18 21:51:58", updated_at: "2014-02-18 21:53:34">]>
```

**Important Note:** Rails will automagically use `people` as the plural of `person`.  So when you create a `Person` model, it will create a `people` database table.

Comment: That looks nice but it's doing three LEFT OUTER JOINs. Wouldn't be better to do two queries? Load Person and Load three cars.

Comment: @AndréBarbosa The question asked for a solution with one query.

Comment: Are left outer joins expensive?

Comment: I'm not criticizing, just wondering if there is a solution with better performance.

Comment: @AndréBarbosa I think there is definitely a better solution.  I would probably just go with your two queries, make sure my tables were properly indexed, then work on caching and cache invalidation for the pages containing this data.

Comment: @CameronMartin joining big tables can be very expensive.

Comment: I posted a possible solution, will update the answer after I've tested it

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally create a join table. Having said that, here's another option: it is possible to define relation based on SQL queries:

```
class Person
  belongs_to :favourite_car, class_name: 'Car'
  belongs_to :business_car, class_name: 'Car'
  belongs_to :home_car, class_name: 'Car'

  has_many :cars, class_name: 'Car', :finder_sql => %q(
   SELECT DISTINCT cars.*
   FROM cars
   WHERE cars.id IN (#{c_ids})
  )

  def c_ids
    [favourite_car_id, business_car_id, home_car_id].compact.uniq.join(',')
  end
end
```

Then you can do Person.includes(:cars)

Comment: This doesn't work. It tries to execute the query `SELECT "cars".* FROM "cars"  WHERE "cars"."person_id" IN (1, 2, 3)`, where 1,2,3 are the person ids.

Comment: That's weird. I modified the answer. Can you try it again?